# Weak convergence in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, banach-spaces

My question is probably very basic, sorry about that.

Let $\{f_i\},\{g_i\}$ be two sequences converging to 0 **weakly** in $L^p[0,1]$ for **any** $p<\infty$. Can one conclude that $\int_0^1f_i(x)g_i(x) dx\to 0$?

Comment: What about  $f_{k}=e^{ikx}$ and $g_{k} = e^{-ikx}$?

Comment: Oops. You are right.Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is No.

Take $f_{k}(x)=e^{ikx}$, and $g_{k}(x)=e^{-ikx}$. Then by [Riemann--Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}f_{k}(x)h(x)dx = \lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1} g_{k}(x)h(x)=0$ for any $h \in L^{q}([0,1])$, for any $1\leq q\leq \infty$. On the other hand $\int_{0}^{1}f_{k}(x)g_{k}(x)dx=1$.